# If a body move around the circle $n$ times then?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, frequency, angular-velocity

What will be its [angular frequency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) if it rotates $n$ time in one second? I know its a homework type question but I am self studying and cannot have someone solve this problem. Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*To understand it in the easiest way either look at it as frequency...*

What you are describing is the *frequency* $f$. The frequency is an amount of turns or revolutions or periods or something else that happen every second. Your frequency here is $n$ turns per second.

Then you have this formula to find angular frequency: $\omega=2 \pi f$

*Or as a number of radians...*

Remember that angular frequency $\omega$ is radians per second. So, since you move $n$ full turns in that second, how many radians are that? Well, one full turn is $2 \pi$ radians, so $n$ turns must be $2 \pi n$ radians.

And this is how many radians you turn per second, which is the angular frequency.